# What is the relationship between the residuals of an objective function and the uncertainties of the minimizer values?

Tags: least-squares, covariance, uncertainty, error-propagation, hessian

Consider I have some optimization problem and an objective function $f(x, y, z)$.

$f$ is defined using the sum of squared residuals, i.e. for some function $g$, we have $f(x, y, z) = \sum[g(x, y, z) - g_{experimental}]_i^2$ for all *i* experimental observations.

From previous reading I understand that if we are able to estimate the hessian matrix $H$ of the objective function $f$ with respect to the minimizer vector $[x, y, z]$, then the inverse of the negative hessian is the estimated covariance matrix of the minimizer values, or

$(-H)^{-1} = cov([x, y, z])$

Finally, the estimated standard deviations of the minimizer values are the square roots of the diagonal elements of the estimated covariance matrix.

1. Is this correct?
2. Furthermore, if I multiply the objective function by some constant, I don't change the minimizer values, but I wildly change the estimated covariance matrix. How is this not a contradiction, or in other words, what counteracts or invalidates changing the objective function's definition?

Comment: Assuming the constant is positive (as it must be), $(2)$ is just a change of units and doesn't modify any meaningful result.  It merely causes all results to be expressed in the new units of measurement.

Comment: In this case, what's special about the $\sum{(x_{exp} - x_{predicted})^2}$ formula, as it pertains to the inverse hessian method above? The way I understood this is that we're relating the concavity of the objective function to the uncertainty of the minimizer. To rephrase my question: What makes using the sum of least squares the only valid objective function to the inverse hessian formula I provided?

Comment: It's not.  What you are doing is a maximum likelihood estimate for errors that are independently and identically distributed with a zero-mean Gaussian.

Comment: I see. Finally, would you mind confirming that the relationship $(-H)^{-1}=cov([x, y, z...])$ is the correct expression, and potentially point me towards a source? Also, you should post the summary of these comments as the solution, as I believe this answers the question adequately and has been quite informative.